# Is there a noun meaning 'book of poetry/poems'?

Tags: vocabulary

There is a noun meaning 'book of fiction': 'novel'.
But there doesn't seem to be a noun meaning 'book of poetry/poems'. Or is there?

Answer (score 1):

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/anthology) gives the word

> **anthology**
>
> **1** A published collection of poems or other pieces of writing.
>   *an anthology of European poetry*

It is usually used for poetry, for example:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately without qualification it doesn't specifically mean a poetry book (since you can have other types of anthology, such as short story anthologies).

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a word. There is a noun phrase "slim volume" that has the chief meaning of "a small book of poems", but this is now a little derogatory:

1920   E. Wallace "The Daffodil Mysteries" - Thornton Lyne was a store-keeper, a Bachelor of Arts,..and the author of a slim volume.

1979   Church Times "Friends will..welcome a slim volume of his poems that has come out."

A novel is not a book - it is a particular type of story.

OED: Novel (n.) A long fictional prose narrative, usually filling one or more volumes and typically representing character and action with some degree of realism and complexity; a book containing such a narrative.

So "He published his novel" approximately means "He published his story." Thus, not all story books contain novels.

Comment: I thought you were right in saying "A novel is not a book - it is a particular type of story." But then your own quote of the OED definition of 'novel' includes "a book containing such a narrative."

Answer (score 0):

The OED regards ***poetry-book*** as something that can be hyphenated, or even written as a single word.

> **poetry-book**
>
> n. 1772   T. Bridges Burlesque Transl. Homer (rev. ed.)
>   Ded. p. ii   Your book's a poetry book, is not it?
>
> 1847   W. M.> Thackeray Vanity Fair (1848) xii. 103   She wrote whole pages out of
>   poetry-books without the least pity.
>
> 2000   San Diego Union-Trib.
>   (Nexis) 18 Apr. (Computer Link Section) 18   Bruce Lansky's books are
>   among America's best-selling children's poetrybooks.

However I do understand your sense that there should be a specific word - of course if one is speaking of psalms one has ***psalter***.

Comment: But this Ngram says the two-word "poetry book" is much more productive than "poetry-book" or "poetrybook": https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poetry+book%2Cpoetry-book%2Cpoetrybook&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoetry%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoetry%20-%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoetrybook%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cpoetry%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoetry%20-%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoetrybook%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @listeneva I suppose what it is telling us is that the fashion for hyphenating composite nouns has varied and is now in decline. However, as recently as 2000 the San-Diego Union-Trib clearly saw fit to express it as a single word. But look [what happens when you add "book of poetry"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=poetry+book%2Cpoetry-book%2Cpoetrybook%2Cbook+of+poetry&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpoetry%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoetry%20-%20book%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpoetrybook%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbook%20of%20poetry%3B%2Cc0)